# InfluxDB sum returned values with same time

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to retrieve the sum of same values that has the same timestamp.

My query is

```
SELECT value FROM dashboards WHERE time >= '2021-03-07T00:00:00Z' AND time <= '2021-03-09T00:00:00Z'
```

My returned values are

```
time                 value
----                 -----
2021-03-07T00:00:00Z 1
2021-03-07T00:00:00Z 1
2021-03-07T00:00:00Z 1
2021-03-08T00:00:00Z 2
2021-03-08T00:00:00Z 2
2021-03-08T00:00:00Z 2
2021-03-09T00:00:00Z 3
2021-03-09T00:00:00Z 3
2021-03-09T00:00:00Z 3
```

How can I change my query the result will be

```
time                 sum
----                 -----
2021-03-07T00:00:00Z 3
2021-03-08T00:00:00Z 6
2021-03-09T00:00:00Z 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM dashboards WHERE time >= '2021-03-07T00:00:00Z' AND time <= '2021-03-09T00:00:00Z' GROUP BY time(1h) FILL(none)
```

GROUP BY time(1h) - group results by time column with interval of 1h

FILL(none) - ignore empty results